# How does casting ternary expression solve overflow compilation error

Tags: c#, casting, compilation

I don't understand how the C# compiler is assigning `works` without a compilation error in the code below. This code compiles and runs correctly, but the second assignment of `worksUnchecked` will not compile if it is not placed in an `unchecked` block.

```
var min = int.MinValue;
uint works = (uint)(min < 0 ? -min : min);
uint worksUnchecked = unchecked((uint)-int.MinValue);
```

Why does the compiler allow the assignment from the ternary expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with the ternary operator per se. Rather, it's because in the context of the ternary operator, you are casting *variable* values at runtime, while in the context of the `uintMin2`, you are casting a *literal* at compile-time.

And the reason this matters is that the default `checked`/`unchecked` context is different at compile time than it is at runtime.

From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx):

> By default, an expression that contains only constant values causes a compiler error if the expression produces a value that is outside the range of the destination type. If the expression contains one or more non-constant values, the compiler does not detect the overflow

Which is another way of saying that, by default, if the compiler can determine that an expression is out-of-range, it will generate an error. If it can't (within the rules of the language specification…that it *theoretically* could by actually tracing the execution of the code at compile-time would be irrelevant), then it won't.

These defaults can be changed, of course. As you've already seen, you can apply `unchecked` to force the compiler to ignore errors at compile-time. You can also use the [`/checked` compiler switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726.aspx) to control what happens at compile-time.

Comment: This makes sense. I tested by wrapping the assignment to `works` with `checked`, and that caused a runtime exception. I was still curious about how the overflow of `-min` as an `int` was being converted to the correct value as a `unit`, so I wrote the following:

```
    var min = int.MinValue;
    
    Console.WriteLine(min);
    Console.WriteLine(-min);
```

and interestingly, the output is for both is `-2147483648`

Comment: First, what I didn't address explicitly in the above is the run-time behavior (you only asked about compile-time). Unless `checked` is applied (via `/checked` switch or `checked` in the code), the _run-time_ behavior is to ignore overflow. As for your observation, that's because in the unchecked context, casting from 32-bit `int` to 32-bit `uint` does not change the binary representation, just the interpretation. Similarly, in 2's complement notation (the way computers represent signed numbers) the negation of `int.MinValue`, which is `0x80000000` is also `0x80000000` (after ignoring overflow)

Answer (score 0):

Based on MSDN:

> The unchecked keyword is used to suppress overflow-checking for integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions.

In other words, its your responsibility that there might be a data loss on your conversion, while casting your variables. If you want to make sure that there is no data loss or overflow, use checked keyword.

The compiler allows your unchecked statement since you are casting the same type:

```
unchecked 
{
uintMin2 = (uint)(-int.MinValue);  //You are casting int.MinValue to uint that's why the compiler allows it.
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The range of the unsigned integer goes form 0 to 4,294,967,295. I don't think you can cast a negative number to be an unsigned integer.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0sksh43.aspx).

Comment: _"I don't think you can cast a negative number to be an unsigned integer"_ -- this is not correct. C# allows casting in unchecked contexts; the signed, negative value is cast to an unsigned, positive value having the same binary representation. E.g. `-1` gets cast to `uint.MaxValue`.